# How do I return a number count of the values inside a variable in chronological order

Tags: javascript, jquery

**For example:**

```
<script>
    var yValues = [apple,organge,carrot]; //this is dynamic and can be more items than 3
    var xValues = [];
</script>
```

**How do I return the xValues in this example in a chronological number:**

```
<script>
    var yValues = [apple,organge,carrot];
    var xValues = [1,2,3]; //these numbers are based on the amount of items in yValues
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does mean `chronological`??

Comment: var xValues =  yValues.map((item, i) => i+1);